# How to read every message in Kafka topic with Spark (using scala) efficiently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a task of reading every message in Kafka topic that has 3 partitions. I have Spark and Scala as tools to do that.

So far I have the following code:

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
      [String, String](cdrTopic, kafkaParams))

kafkaStream.foreachRDD { rdd => {

      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {

        rdd.foreachPartition(iterator => {

          while (iterator.hasNext) {

            val partition = iterator.next().value().split("\\n")

            if (!partition.isEmpty) {

              partition.foreach(string => {

                if (!string.isEmpty) {

                  //process every message here
                }

              })
            }

            println("no partition data")

          }

        })

      }
      println("no rdd data to process")
      }
    }
```

Each message is a tsv (tab seperated values) string that I need to parse and save to db.

I believe this to be very inefficient because I am using 4 loops and I think some of the data is getting lost as the number of messages written to db is very low.

I am using using scala version 2.11.12, spark-streaming 2.4.0, spark-streaming-kafka 2.4.0.

Is there any efficient way of reading and parsing every message in kafka using spark?

Comment: Hi @Aidai which database are you planning to use?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis I am currently inserting data to Ignite. But also planning to implement persist to PostgreSql.